# How do I append an Image in the DOM from a list using EncodedAbsUrl

Tags: javascript, sharepoint

I have 2 lists with 5 columns; one has Title, Question, Attorneys, ID, and attorneyPic. This last one is looking into an image list. I created a webpart for this so the the actual webpart looks like this.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

 apiUrl = "/Legal/Attorneys/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('attorneysBio')/items$select=*,EncodedAbsUrl,attorneysPic/Title&$expand=attorneysPic/Id";
    topicsTitle = '';
    title = 'TITLE HERE';

</script>
```

The javascript code looks like this

```
var buildCards = function () {
                    if (filterTopic.length !== 0) {
                        for (i = 0; i < filterTopic.length; i++) {
                            var accID2 = accID.replace(/\s/g, '');
                            var faqItems = filterTopic[i]
                            var headerID = "heading" + faqItems.ID
                            var cardBodyID = "collapse" + faqItems.ID
                            var cardTitle = faqItems.Title
                            var cardBody = faqItems.Question
                            var attorneyPics = faqItems.attorneysPic.EncodedAbsUrl
                            console.log(attorneyPics)

                            var cardBuild = '<div class="card">' +
                                '<div class="card-header pb-1 pl-0" role="tab" id="' + headerID + '">' +
                                '<a class="collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#' + accID2 + '" href="#' + cardBodyID + '" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="' + cardBodyID + '">' +
                                '<h5 class="mb-0 font-thin">' + cardTitle + '<span class="rotate"></span></h5>' +
                                '</a>' +
                                '</div>' +
                                '<div id="' + cardBodyID + '" class="collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="' + headerID + '" data-parent="#' + accID + '">' +
                                '<div class="row"><div class="col-md-3"><img src="'+attorneyPics+'" class="img-responsive"></div>' +
                                '<div class="col-md-9"><div class="card-body py-1 pl-0"><p>' + cardBody + '</p></div></div></div>' +
                                '</div>' +
                                '</div>'
                            $(".accordion").append(cardBuild);
                        };
                    } else {
                        var cardBuild = '<h4>There are no results matching your search.</div>'
                        $(".accordion").append(cardBuild);
                    }
```

What is happening is that the url given is the one from the actual list and not from the list items "https://browardauthor/Legal/Attorneys/Lists/attorneysBio/1_.000"

Comment: is image list a document library, storing images as files/documents? as solution depends upon how you are storing the image. is it a file in document library, or a URL (Hyperlink or Picture) column

Comment: Hello I am storing the images in an image library and the column is an URL (image)

Comment: you may try to compose url by yourself `[yoursite]/[listName]/[ImageFileNameWithExtension]` OR try bringing `FileRef` in you api call e.g.  `$select=*,EncodedAbsUrl,attorneysPic/Title,attorneysPic/FileRef`